# How to apply InputFilter to EditTextPreferences?

Tags: android, filter, preferences

I want to apply InputFilter to my EditTextPreferences...

Before I used the PreferenceActivity I had EditTexts with Filters like that:

```
            et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ETminsim);
            et3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ETdelay);

            et1.setText(Integer.toString(PlotView.playlist_size), EditText.BufferType.EDITABLE);

            et2.setText(Integer.toString(conversorToInt(PlotView.min_sim)), EditText.BufferType.EDITABLE);
            et3.setText(Integer.toString(MusicService.getSeek()/1000), EditText.BufferType.EDITABLE);

            et1.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilterMinMax(1, 30)});
            et2.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilterMinMax(0, 100)});
            et3.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilterMinMax(0, 300)});
```

But how can I reference to the EditTexts of the EditTextPreference in order to set these Filters?

My new Code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
                 super.onCreate(bundle);

                 getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName(Singleton.PREFS_NAME);
                 addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);

                 //TODO set InputFilter
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Konstantin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10581576/910718) had it mostly correct. Combine his answer with Sebastian's comment on his answer and you get

```
EditText editText1 = ((EditTextPreference) findPreference(preference_1_key))
                         .getEditText();
editText1.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilterMinMax(1, 30) });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your preference Activity and you can get the items by id:

```
        EditTextPreference editTextPreference = findByViewId(R.id.editPref1);
        EditText editText = editTextPreference.getEditText();
        editText.setFilters(................);
```

Comment: This is wrong, I found another way:

EditTextPreference delay = (EditTextPreference)findPreference("@string/pref_delay");

But I cannot set the Filter on the delay Object.

Answer (score 0):

**This has more flexibility.**

```
public class Utility {
public static void setEditTextInputFilter(EditText editText, final String blockCharacterSet) {
    InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {

        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

            if (source != null && blockCharacterSet.contains(("" + source))) {
                return "";
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
}
```

}

**How to use:**

exampleEditText is the editText which want to block input "-".

```
Utility.setEditTextInputFilter(exampleEditText, "-");
```