# set the range of numbers from 2 to 1000 in an edit text box in android

Tags: android

In My application I have an edit text box in which user is allowed to enter numbers only from 2 to 1000. I have already implemented the validation for this,,

Eg. if the number entered in lesser than "2" set-text should be "2"and i am saving these values in a shared preference file on click of button and retaining these input values for further use.

Here is problem occurring when user is entering any number more than 1000 or less than 2, and press the phone's back key than click on the button,it saves the incorrect values which are even not allowed.

I have also implemented the back pressed() method but if the keypad is up,,I m still able to use the back key. I am trying to do something where user will even not be able to enter any number which is more than 1000. Either keypad stops working or it get disable,something like this,that the edit text box even don't take any incorrect value..

in short I want to set a range of numbers that a edit text box can take a input.

please help

Comment: You can use InputFilter on your EditText. 
You can use [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581337/how-to-apply-inputfilter-to-edittextpreferences] or [this] http://www.almadevelop.com/2011/11/android-how-to-use-inputfilter-with.html

Answer (score 2):

Instead of button click validation ,you can use Textwatcher
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

example

```
editext1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                // YOur Code
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

First make this class :

```
package com.test;

import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.Spanned;

public class InputFilterMinMax implements InputFilter {

    private int min, max;

    public InputFilterMinMax(int min, int max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public InputFilterMinMax(String min, String max) {
        this.min = Integer.parseInt(min);
        this.max = Integer.parseInt(max);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {   
        try {
            int input = Integer.parseInt(dest.toString() + source.toString());
            if (isInRange(min, max, input))
                return null;
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { }     
        return "";
    }

    private boolean isInRange(int a, int b, int c) {
        return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
    }
}
```

Then use this from your Activity :

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
et.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilterMinMax("1", "12")});
```

This will allow user to enter values from 1 to 12 only.

EDIT :

```
Set your edittext with android:inputType="number".
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the keyboard like this:

```
 InputMethodManager ipmm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            ipmm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(url.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Where `url` is :

```
url = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eT_webbrowser);
```

Comment: Thank you,, but this code s giving some error saying that"syntax error on token "hideSoftInputFromWindow", Identifier expected after this token"

Comment: it's working perfectly for me in my code. In my case, After I enter the webaddress in the EditText, I'm disabling the soft keyboard and it just works...Check it again.

Comment: i have checked it several times...not working..:(,, in my code i want to disable the keyboard once user enter anything greater than 1000. can you please advise that how can where this code should be written to disable the keyboard.

Comment: Because you wanted the user to enter the input and using your code you are validating the inputs., Please use this code after your validation lines of code.